# Redirect React Component when submit form express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redirect, submit

I'm trying to redirect to a React Component when submit the form with express. This is my code:

**Express.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'))
})

app.post('/charge', (req, res) => {

    const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

    stripe.charges.create({
        amount: req.body.totalAmount * 100,
        currency: 'eur',
        source: req.body.stripeToken,
        description: "Example charge",
        receipt_email: req.body.receiptEmail
    }).then((charge) => {
        console.log(req.body)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

**CheckoutForm.js**

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            this.props.stripe.createToken({ name: this.state.name }).then(({ token }) => {
                console.log(token)
                this.stripeTokenHandler(token)
            }) 


        }

        stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
            const form = document.getElementById('form')

            const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input')
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken')
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id)

            form.appendChild(hiddenInput)
            form.submit()       
        }

render() {
        return (
            <div className="payment-container">    
                <form id="form" className="checkout-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                    <label>
                        Card Number
                        <CardNumberElement
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            style={{ base: { color: 'white' } }}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Titular Name
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={this.handleText}
                            className="input-text"
                            placeholder="Full Name"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Expiration Date
                        <CardExpiryElement style={{base: {color: 'white'}}} />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        CVC
                        <CardCVCElement style={{base: {color: 'white'}}} />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={this.handleEmail}
                            className="input-text"
                            name="receiptEmail"
                            placeholder="Email"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button className="btn-buy">Pay now</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )}
}
```

The form submitted correctly and register the payment. When I submitted now gets the request body. What's the way to redirect a component with the request form?

Comment: hi Victor. You mean after you click "Pay Now" you want it to redirect?

Comment: I posted an answer below for you based on your needs as I understand them. If it helps you, please mark it as accepted. If not please feel free to reply to it with further questions related specifically to this and I'll help you out. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have a component called ChargePage with path '/charge'. So I want when click submit redirect to Component path '/charge' with the request data.

Comment: Perfect. That's outlined below. I'll update my answer to use your exact path.

Comment: you wanted the REQUEST data or the RESPONSE data? Just to be sure...

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is your component to redirect once you hit the "Pay Now" button then I suggest you change your `<button>` to a `<Link>` component using React Router.

It would look like this

```
<Link to='/charge' className='btn-buy' onClick={this.formSubmit}>Pay Now</Link>
```

Then just remove the `this.formSubmit` from the form itself since its now on the button. It will redirect and submit.

If you want to WAIT to redirect after you get a reply, then in your `formSubmit` function, after you get a reply back from the server you can use `this.props.history.push('/charge')` in then `then` portion of your form submitter.

Keep in mind you will need to `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'` for this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: He said he wants to redirect "with the request data". Can you show how that is possible?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I missed that. Want to verify he wants the request data though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could handle this is by using a `Redirect` component from React Router. Something like this:

```
// in the route, if the post was successful
res.json({data: 'whatever data you want', success: true})
// and if it was unsuccessful
res.json({success: false})
```

And here's a really stripped down react component to go with it:

```
class FormComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      // inputs or whatever
      success: true,
    }
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('send the data', { with: 'some options' })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(jsonRes => {
        const { success } = jsonRes;
        this.setState({ success });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  // assorted other stuff to handle inputs or whatever

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          {/* inputs or whatever */}
        </form>
        {this.state.success && <Redirect push to='/some-other-url' />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If `this.state.success` evaluates to `true`, the redirect will render; otherwise, it won't at all.

This allows you to make sure the request was successful before redirecting to another page. It also lets you give the user an error message, do something with whatever the response is, etc etc. Maybe you'd need to move the state and so on further up your component tree so more components have access to the response data, if that's something they need.